# How to get the field name from firestore document

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to get the field value but I am struggling with getting the field name.

[image: example screenshot]

I have been trying the dig through the documentation if I could find something but have been unsuccessful in my attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [retrieve a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) from Firestore, you get a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html). When you get the `data()` from a `DocumentSnapshot` it returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`, and from that you can get the `keys`.

So:

```
final docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
docRef.get().then(
  (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final keys = data.keys; // 
    // ...
  },
  onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
);
```